# Alternative to GetFileInformationByHandleEx/FileIdInfo for Windows 7?

Tags: windows, api, filesystems

The MS docs state that the FileIdInfo enum for GetFileInformationByHandleEx is only available in Windows 8 and above.

Is there an alternative function that returns the same FileIndexHigh/FileIndexLow info for a particular file for Windows 7?

Comment: [`NtQueryInformationFile`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/ddi/ntifs/nf-ntifs-ntqueryinformationfile) with [`FileInternalInformation`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/ddi/ntifs/ns-ntifs-_file_internal_information) - this work even in win2000. exist also `FileIdInformation` too, but this think also only from win8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`GetFileInformationByHandle` (the non-Ex older function) exists on all versions of NT and provides the file id.

Note: You should try the Ex version first if it is there because ReFS uses 128-bit file ids!